# Difference between AとB and AやB

Tags: word-choice, particle-と, particle-や

Is it grammatically correct to say something like:

> 友達と遊ぶこと**や**食べることが好きです。

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: Yes, it is grammatically correct.

---

For your info / what you are not clear of:

> 友達と遊ぶこと**と**食べることが好きです。
> I love to eat and play with friends.
> (And thats all, not sure if I love to do anything else with them. )
>
> 友達と遊ぶこと**や**食べることが好きです。
> I love to eat and play with friends.
> (Well actually there are much more I love to do with my friends but play and eat will be two of them.)

So the difference of と and や will be：

- と： *list things out and that's everything of it.*
- や： *list a part of all things out that belongs to the same group.*

That is also why according for some Japanese と got the nuance of more "separating" and や feels more like things belongs to the same group.

Hope that helps.^^

Comment: How about expressing like?  と：list things; and that's everything of it   や： list a part of all things that belong to the same group

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick [Google ブックス](https://books.google.co.jp/) search for "ことや" and got results such as:

- > なにかしらの心的態度を変える**ことや**、しているなにかをやめる**ことや**、やり方を変える**ことや**…
- > 能天気にラッキーな**ことや**ツイてる**ことや**、いいことばかりとは限りません。いやな**ことや**、辛い**ことや**…
- > 辞職にも通ずる**ことや**し…

Based on the results, I think it's safe to say that it's grammatically correct. However, there are more common ways to express strings of verbs like とか or 〜たり〜たりする.

Comment: 「辞職にも通ずることやし」の「や」は、関西弁のcopula「だ」やと思いますけど・・（「～ことだし」を関西弁で言うと「～ことやし」になるわけやし）